# Catalog of Question Types

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

In an effort to start building consensus after asking: [Enough is enough. NOBODY can obey rules that are only in someone's head](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6074/enough-is-enough-nobody-can-obey-rules-that-are-only-in-someones-head), I'd like to start with what I hope will become a canonical catalog or list of question types we can refer new users toward to help improve site question quality.  Obviously it's impossible for this list to encompass 100% of every type of question that could be asked on a creative site like Worldbuilding, but I'm hoping that it'll cover enough that the outliers needn't be worried about.

Before adding a question pattern to the answer list below, please take the time to read through the posts to be absolutely sure you're not materially duplicating patterns.  If you have a pattern that is a duplicate but useful to identify, please edit the answer and add it to the "alternate patterns" list.

Upvotes mean the question pattern, description, and advice concerning the question are good and worthy of being canonical (this includes both "we like this pattern" and "we don't like this pattern").  If you are adding to what already exists, please edit the answer.  If you are changing or deleting something that already exists (and you're not the original answerer), please use comments to petition the answerer first.

Downvotes may mean the question pattern has already been listed (a comment explaining this would be appropriate), that the pattern description is insufficient, or that the pattern is simply not worthy.  If you're downvoting to indicate required improvement, please remember to check back and remove the downvote when/if the post improved.

Answer template:

---

> Question pattern

**Alternate Patterns:** Lorem Ipsum (this optional block lists alternative versions of the question pattern.  The purpose is clarification, not simply listing permutaitons.)...

**Suitable:** On-Topic/Off-Topic

**Description:** Lorem ipsum (why this is/isn't a good question for WB, etc.)...

**Traps to Avoid:** Lorem ipsum (this optional block helps users understand how to avoid the most common VTC reasons for this pattern)...

**Relevant Meta Links:**

- Links to pre-existing pre-existing questions
- that discuss, describe, support, or refutes this pattern.

Comment: Thanks for starting this! I agree that it's a herculean labour to list every type of desirable question type!, but perhaps at least a discussion of some of the less obvious on-topic and more contentious off-topic questions can help us sort out some issues.

Comment: I think while this is a good idea in theory, a lot of questions can fall in a grey area. There is always specific cases.

Comment: @Vincent, I agree and understand.  It's a starting point.  There's a lot of us mid-generation users who didn't benefit from the discussions of you first-generation users when the rules were made.  Now there are late-generation users who are having even greater trouble due to the mid-generation ambiguity.  At list this catalog will give everyone a foundation to use when discussing whether or not a specific question is suitable.

Comment: I swear we've done something similar before, with the user question analysis series

Comment: @Aify, I thought so too, but an (albeit quick) search didn't turn anything up.

Comment: @JBH It was the Case Study series; here it is https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3048/case-study-series?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Actually, I think the Case Study series might be better than this post since it provides concrete examples to look at in each post.

Comment: We need a post for the off-topic "how would society react if X happened".

Comment: @Renan, We already have one, the more general "How would X change if Y?" question.  X can be society, climate, "the world", "the universe", etc.  What makes this question off-topic is a failure of scope (too broad).  It's not inherently off-topic.

Comment: @Aify, I'm looking into how to integrate them.  They have better examples, but the solution is difficult to approach, like reading a list of rules without an index.  between the two we should be able to come closer to perfect.

Comment: Is a post about "I need Y, how do I get from X?" needed? Where you work backwards from a needed result. Could be borderline off topic/idea generation without clear answer parameters. Some of my questions that fit this, would be [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/73889/where-is-the-best-place-to-park-your-damaged-spaceship-longterm) [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/69564/how-could-immortal-children-age-faster-than-immortal-adults) and [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/71897/why-would-patent-terms-be-extended-to-centuries)

Comment: @EveryBitHelps, I apologize for not following up with your question sooner.  I [took a crack at it](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types/6339#6339) due to the need to create the counter-balance to "Why would someone X?"

Answer (score 12):

> I need an *infinite list* of things.

**Suitable:** Off-Topic

**Description:** These questions are usually idea-generating questions and are easily identified by their unconstrained nature.  For example, "what should I name my city?"  Despite descriptions of the city, its surrounds, its founders, etc., the fact is the city can be named anything, resulting in lengthly lists and promoting unproductive answers.

**Relevant Meta Links:**

- [Is name choice on-topic for Worldbuilding?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6125/is-name-choice-on-topic-for-worldbuilding/6137#6137)
- [Clarification for new users: when is a "fishing for ideas" question on- or off-topic?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5621/clarification-for-new-users-when-is-a-fishing-for-ideas-question-on-or-off-t)

**Relevant Help Center Rules:**

- To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … every answer is equally valid. ([Source](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask))
- Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much. ([Source](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask))
- If you are looking for discussion, brainstorming, or an overall process rather than specific questions and answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question. ([Source](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))

**Advice:** A clever way to begin the process of idea-generation (introduced by our renowned Cort Ammon), is to reformat your question as "what [genre] books or movies have dealt with [open-ended-idea]?" and ask it on our sister site, [Science-Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/).  People will happily give you a ton of useful information that could (a) directly answer your question or (b) help you narrow your question so it becomes an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609) question on this site.

Alternatively, provide a list of restrictions, conditions, limitations, and expectations to help guide respondents as they answer the question. Helping us understand why you asked your question, what's stopping you from answering it yourself, and how you expect to use the answers can also help. These can also narrow the question to become an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609).

Comment: Yep. Also probably "too broad".

Comment: I'd say this one is Primarily Opinion Based, because the main issue is, as you say, just about any answer is as good as any other

Comment: This finite list of things seems to be something you constructed yourself out of whole cloth. Can you provide a link to a discussion where such a standard was proposed and adopted by the community?

Comment: @sphennings This is NOT a meta post. If you want to challenge the policy, post a new question about the matter. The +11 on this question is the community approval. I'm sure you have the chops to search Meta for list questions rather than expecting someobody else to prove to you the world is round.

Comment: @JBH Are you seriously claiming that an off hand remark in an upvoted answer to something unrelated, can be construed as community discussion and buy in around a change to site policy? It's an upvoted question, but I wouldn't call this a policy discussion, especially if you are arguing that an off hand comment in a categorization of questions is proof of community agreement. It's likely that the upvotes are for people showing that they agree that infinite lists are inappropriate. If there was  community adoption of this policy it should be easy to link to it. Or are you grasping at straws?

Comment: If you truly think that an off hand remark in a well received answer is enough to create new site policy, then because of an off hand remark I made in [this answer](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8571/26175) it is now site policy that every question must demonstrate worldbuilding purpose. I'd argue that while worldbuilding purpose is a decent standard for assessing whether a question is on topic for this site, it isn't this site's policy that every question must demonstrate worldbuilding purpose. It certainly hasn't been proposed or adopted by the community.

Answer (score 12):

> I need a situation that would enable a character to (do) X

**Suitable:** Off-Topic

**Description:** These questions are about a story set in a world, not about world building. They are sometimes fit for https://writing.stackexchange.com.

**Relevant Meta Links:**

- [Why is my question "Too Story Based" and how do I get it opened?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300/21222)
- [When should I close a question as "Too Story Based"?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3298/21222)

*Edit from JBH: User Elemtilas once pointed out in a comment that the answer to this question type is often a function of **[narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609).**  In other words, the OP is looking for any way to rationalize the condition "X."  If "X" is an absolute requirement for your story, then it's no longer a worldbuilding question as it has become story-based.  This question type is very susceptible to depending on narrative necessity.*

Comment: The Edit fails to comprehend the difference between narrative necessity *per se* and the worldbuilding needed to make a story work. Example: DC writers needed to stop Superman doing everything unstoppably. Answer: kryptonite. Kryptonite is now part of Superman's world. A relevant worldbuilding question could what scientific explanation is for how kryptonite weakens Superman? The difference is between *what* happens in story (narrative) and *how* it happens (the worldbuilding element). Carefully distinguish between narrative necessity & worldbuilding which is often in service to the story.

Comment: @a4android It's a thin distinction, but kryptonite represents an actual world rule (a material that exists in the world that has a desirable effect or achieves a desirable goal, not unlike any other *unobtanium* out there) where this question type concerns *situations* or story-based explanations such as a viable back-story.

Answer (score 9):

> I need a *finite list* of things

**Suitable:** On-Topic

**Description:** These questions seek insight into a class of issues (I use "class" in the programming sense) that often leads to a bullet list of items.  for example, "what are different types of tectonic stress?" or "what are the different governmental types I can use?"  These questions result in a finite list of items and a good answer addresses as much of that list as is appropriate for the question with thorough descriptions for each item.

**Traps to Avoid:** While generally on-topic, these questions are frequently closed as primarily opinion-based because the OP has not performed enough initial research.  A simple list of cloud types, for example, is easily and quickly found via a Google search.  Questions of this type should be clear, focused, and have already performed basic research.

Comment: [tag:worldbuilding-resources] questions, such as [Database of real historical names](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/91026/28789), might be relevant to this topic, too. They produce a short list of resources, which in turn have *very* long lists of *something*.

Comment: @Secespitus, I'm completely happy with that, from the SE perspective it's a concise and definitive answer.

Comment: I would disagree that "What are the different government types I can use?" is a finite list.  It is only finite if the number of types of government is limited, and that's not so.  For example, what if I say the types of government are democracy, republic, oligarchy, and dictatorship.  That's it.  That's somewhat defensible.  For example, an absolute monarchy could be considered a hereditary dictatorship.  But what if it's the difference between a constitutional monarchy and an absolute monarchy that make the system work in terms of the question?  Types of governments are shades of gray.

Comment: @Brythan, thank you for your insight.  Do you have a better example we can use to illustrate a positive example?  I'm all for improving the canonicity of the category.

Comment: "I use "class" in the programming sense" Can you elaborate? What does it mean?

Comment: @user161005 Nearly all questions like this are sub-types of the same basic question. From a programming perspective: finite_list.list_of_reasons_A, finite_list.list_of_reasons_B... The questions literally all have the same form and vary only by the list of restrictions, limitations, conditions, and directives for what constitutes a best answer. Note that the goal is to create a question where a single person can believable provide a thorough (if not exhaustive) list of a page or less. Compare this to the infinite list Qs where it's unbelievable that any one person could do that.

Comment: There are plenty of finite lists that are too broad. Remember the standard in the help center is "many valid answers". Can you cite a meta discussion where this is adopted by the community or did you create this standard yourself in this answer without seeking community discussion or buy in? The closest I can see is a rejection of infinite lists. This does not then imply that every finite list is permitted, just that infinite lists are obviously not ok.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible to X

**Alternate Patterns:** What do you think about X?

**Suitability:** On-Topic

**Description:** These questions frequently ask Worldbuilding participants to verify the feasibility of a design, concept, or idea.  Questions of this type should use the [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) tag and comply with its requirements.  (See the "[Is X Realistic?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types/6556#6556)" answer to this post.)

**Traps to Avoid:** Questions of this type easily become off-topic (too broad) because they can violate the basic rule of Stack Exchange: [that they are Q&A sites, not discussion forums](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).  This can also easily become Too Broad if the question is [How is this possible?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/2113)

Comment: I will object, because there are many good questions that ask if something is possible (even though their titles don't start with *"is it possible"*). I will comment some links to them.

Comment: TL;DR: the pattern "is it possible" is at the very core of the reality check tag. It is also tied strongly to the science based and hard science tags.

Comment: @Renan, When I originally wrote this I had the "I need an infinite list of things" question in mind, but that discussion hadn't happened yet and your point is very well taken.  I've rewritten the answer (and would appreciate it if you deleted all the example question comments).  Thanks!

Comment: Done, and I've reversed my vote.

Answer (score 7):

> How would X change if Y

**Suitable:** On-Topic

**Description:** These questions ask what the consequences would be if something we consider normal were changed.  For example, such a question may ask about the effect on climate if planetary axial tilt changes, or the effects on society if a particular technology is introduced (or removed), or the effects on history if a particular person was never born.

**Traps to Avoid:** While generally on-topic, these questions are frequently closed as too broad or too primarily opinion-based because the OP has not performed enough research to ask a specific question.  For example, asking "how would the weather change if the Earth was 10% closer to the sun" is too broad because climate is so complex and entire book would be required to provide a definitive answer.  Likewise, "How would society have changed if television was invented twenty years earlier?" is primarily opinion-based because there is no clear way to judge the quality of the answers.

**Relevant Meta Links:**

- [How to deal with "I have a High Concept, please do my work for me" questions?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions)

Answer (score 6):

> What is the best name for X?

**Alternate Patterns:** What should I call my X?

**Suitability:** Off-Topic

**Description:** These questions are fishing-for-ideas questions seeking help with an aestheic component ("window dressing") of a story rather than a rule of a fictional world.  They always fall into one or both of two categories:

- **Too Story-Based** The question is asking for a name that can only be suitable within the context of the story (e.g., "My aliens are a warrior race, what would be a good name for them?").
- **Primarily Opinion-Based** If the question is not too story-based, then it is always primarily opinion-based as no amount of limitation will remove the aesthetic "I like this one best just because" judgment of the OP.  In short, no amount of limitation will completely distinguise one answer as the best answer.

Comment: *"They always fall into one or both of two categories"*  -  Not  true.  Or at   least  does not  have  to be  true. Making  consistent name origins can be  objective.

Comment: @Mołot, I'm willing to believe.  Do we have an example of an objective name request?  Every one I've dealt with was basically a fishing-for-ideas infinite list question.

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/55809/809 | https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/4087/809 | https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3478/809

Comment: @Mołot, All three of those examples are asking, "what method can I use to create names?"  That sounds like worldbuilding to me as it's describing the process (if defined well enough) and not simply the much more subjective result.  Would you agree?  If so, I'll leave this entry as-is and create a second entry for the "what method could I use..." version.

Comment: @JBH Correct: there is a clear difference between "method for naming" and "preference for a name"!  It seems like any iteration of "What's the best..." is a synonym for "What's your opinion..." and thus is off-topic as written. Very narrowly, a question like "Given this and that historical constraint and given X, Y, and Z phonological constraints of the language, which form of the name Q might be the most likely outcome?" And even then, that particular question might best be shunted over to Constructed Langauges SE!!

Answer (score 6):

> How do I get from X to Y?

**Suitable:** On-Topic

**Description:** Questions asking for help applying the rules of a world.  For example, "If my world's atmosphere is 90% oxygen, how to I stop the Boy Scouts from burning my planet to crisp?"  Properly scoped, this question is a specific version of the "I need a *finite list* of things" question.

**Traps to Avoid:** Asking how to apply the rules of your world treads the very thin line between your question being too story-based and primarily opinion-based.  This balance, however, is important to avoid question closure.  The question must ask for answers that are generally applicable to *any story* in your world, not specific to just one story.  They must also be bound by the rules of your world, and explaining those rules are a requirement for this question.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the answer to this maths problem?

**Alternate Patterns:**  How much energy do I get if XYZ? (I use atomic bombs, I initiate a matter-antimatter reaction, etc)

**Suitability:**  Off-Topic

**Description:**  Questions that ask for numeric quantities or for participants to plug numbers into an equation do not directly relate to the conception, making or shaping of a fictional world.

**Traps to Avoid:**  This kind of question is easy to avoid by basic online research. I.e., a Google search. Simple maths questions posed here show no obvious research or demonstration of relevant context.

**Relevant Meta Links:**  In general, see [*What Topics Can I Post About (in Worldbuilding)?*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); also [*What Topics Can I Ask About (in Mathematics)?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); and [*What Topics Can I Ask About (in Physics)?*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

**Notes:**  The intention here is not to "ban" maths questions per se. Rather it is to shunt simple maths questions to a more appropriate part of SE while simultaneously improving the worldbuilding content of maths questions that do hinge on e.g. an equation dealing with some function of Nature and that we should be dealing with here at Worldbuilding.

The off-topicality of this specific question type derives from its purely "do my homework for me by plugging numbers into an equation and give me the answer" attitude. We should discourage that behaviour; we should continue to be encouraging of querents who need help with difficult physics or geometry in a clearly defined worldbuilding context.

Examples of On-Topic Maths/Worldbuilding Questions:

- [*Calculating the Area of a Country on a Map*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3859/how-do-i-calculate-the-area-of-a-specific-place-on-the-map)
- [*Going from a Spherical Map to a Planar Map*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/109633/how-to-generate-world-map-for-minimal-distortion)
- [*How Much Does a Moon's Gravity Affect Free Fall Acceleration on a Planet*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/111439/how-much-does-a-moon-s-gravity-effect-the-free-fall-acceleration-of-an-object)
- [*A Universe Where Mathematics Are Different*](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31722/universe-where-mathematics-is-different)

Comment: While I agree with your general idea, there are some questions which are on-topic that may fit into this category. I think it should be narrowed somewhat. "What is the answer to this maths problem" is generally the acceptance criteria for the [reality-check] tag

Comment: This is easily applied to algebra problems, but what about calculus problems that are often beyond the OP?  You can't google what you don't understand.  Is asking "how fast can an unladen European swallow fly" off topic as a math problem?  Can you provide an example question from the Main site to help clarify the question?

Comment: @bendl I agree with you 100% that there may be varieties of this question type that are on-topic. A pure plug in the numbers question, no. A question that seeks to explore likely or plausible sequelae, yeah that would definitely fall under reality check.

Comment: This would be a dangerous general thing to make off topic and violates the precedent set on the site thus far.

Comment: @JBH To be honest, even algebra & geometry equations are beyond this poor geopoet! I would never ask the community to just plug numbers into an equation for me; but, if I needed help with geometry-in-context, then yeah, I'd ask here. Case in point was a while ago question about calculating the area of a country from its shape on a map. That's a perfect example of on-topic mathematics. Examples to follow.

Comment: Examples of what I'd consider to be on-topic mathematics questions: [example](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3859/how-do-i-calculate-the-area-of-a-specific-place-on-the-map) | [example](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/109633/how-to-generate-world-map-for-minimal-distortion) | [example](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/111439/how-much-does-a-moon-s-gravity-effect-the-free-fall-acceleration-of-an-object) | [example](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31722/universe-where-mathematics-is-different)

Comment: @James Why would it be dangerous? As I see it, if the community has long allowed *this kind* off-topic questions to be asked and answered, then we really should be answering *all kinds* of off-topic questions. Like a general discussion forum. I think one of the roots of this discussion is to seek consensus and consistency on policy. What this comes down to: I am more than happy to upvote & answer **ALL** off topic / low quality questions (if I like them) if we're not going to create & follow a consistent policy.

Comment: A  blanket ban on these questions doesn't make sense and doesn't follow site precedent, that is all I am saying.  Questions should still meet a standard but making them all off topic is wrong in my view.

Comment: I see. I'm not asking for a "blanket ban", just perhaps being a little more selective as regards welcome question types. Giving the answers to  math problems, whether it's been done in the past or not, I think really is beyond the scope of worldbuilding. Also I'm asking our querents to raise their own bar a little: if you've got a mathematical question that touches upon worldbuilding, then demonstrate the connexion! How does our filling in the blanks of an equation help to build a world?

Comment: You and James bring up a good points and you should consider editing your answer to accomodate it.  when you do, remember to put yourself into the shoes of someone specifically not you, be sure you see what you intend through their eyes, too.

Comment: (Done and done.)

Answer (score 3):

> How to build a world?

**Alternate Patterns:** How do I go about worldbuilding?  What process should I use to build my world?  Where do I start with worldbuilding?

**Suitable:** Off-Topic

**Description:** It is completely natural to ask "how do I go about building my world" on a site dedicated to worldbuilding.  However, there are a great many ways to accomplish this one goal and dozens (if not hundreds) of websites dedicated to answering this very question.  These questions are excellent candidates for the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) due to the often subjective nature of the topic.

Comment: As asked, I'd consider this question far too broad. You yourself say there are a great many ways to go about it; there are many starting points, ending points; there are differing goals & rationales that all impinge on the mechanics. I definitely agree about restrictions: specific processes, specific end goals.

Comment: @elemtilas, Do you recommend modifications to this entry?  I'm 100% in favor of clear descriptions.

Comment: Well, perhaps. I'd suggest marking "how do I build a world" as off-topic / (way!) too broad; but perhaps add one or two of the extended / focused questions as new questions. Like perhaps "what are some strategies for applying real world physics to a fundamentally fantastic / slightly unpredictable world" or "what are three (or five) first considerations I should be thinking about when beginning a new world?" and mark those as on-topic.

Comment: @elemtilas, after reading your comment and doing a 5-second google search for "worldbuilding 'how to'" I'm 100% convinced.

Comment: I think that's a positive edit! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Is X realistic?

**Alternate Patterns:** Is X plausible?  Would [something previously stated] work?

**Suitable:** On-Topic

**Description:** Questions asking if the application of world rules to achieve a specified effect are on-topic.  Your question should be asked such that the only answers can be of the form, "Yes, because..." and "No, because...".  Questions of this type should always use the [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) tag.  Please note from the tag's description:

> Asks if a given concept is realistic in a given context.

You are required to provide a specific context including all of the necessary world-rules to properly frame the reality-check query.  Said another way, you need to completely define the reality you're asking us to check.

**Traps to Avoid:** [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110), therefore you must avoid asking your question in a way that invites discussion.  For example, "Is there a better way to X?" or "if this doesn't work, what alternatives could I use?"  Inviting a discussion makes the question *too broad.*

**Relevant Meta Links:**

- [Why is my question about the feasibility of keeping different tools outside in threat considered off-topic by some?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5593/why-is-my-question-about-the-feasibility-of-keeping-different-tools-outside-in-t)
- [Could redefining Reality-Check and the assumed proof standard be useful?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5307/could-redefining-reality-check-and-the-assumed-proof-standard-be-useful)
- [Do we need the reality-check tag?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/do-we-need-the-reality-check-tag)
- [Where does Reality-Check actually fit in the burden of proof framework?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/where-does-reality-check-actually-fit-in-the-burden-of-proof-framework)
- [We say we don't allow reality checks of plot elements - but is it true?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4965/we-say-we-dont-allow-reality-checks-of-plot-elements-but-is-it-true)
- [Should we finally allow reality checks of other plot elements?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4931/should-we-finally-allow-reality-checks-of-other-plot-elements)
- [Does the low tolerance for opinion-based questions make the tag reality-check unnecessary?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4919/does-the-low-tolerance-for-opinion-based-questions-make-the-tag-reality-check-un)
- [Let's break down reality-check](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4468/lets-break-down-reality-check)
- [Challenging Questions' Premises](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4225/challenging-questions-premises)
- [According to reality check, possibility implies existence](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4172/according-to-reality-check-possibility-implies-existence)
- [When is "that's not possible" an appropriate answer?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3758/when-is-thats-not-possible-an-appropriate-answer)
- [What's the difference between 'reality-check' and 'science-based' or even 'hard-science'?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3702/whats-the-difference-between-reality-check-and-science-based-or-even-hard)
- [Ontology of Question Types](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3064/ontology-of-question-types)
- [Reality Checking on questions not tagged "reality-check" | or ask questions differently?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2679/reality-checking-on-questions-not-tagged-reality-check-or-ask-questions-diff)
- [Tearing apart questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/tearing-apart-questions)
- [How realistic should a question tagged "reality-check" be?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/how-realistic-should-a-question-tagged-reality-check-be)

Answer (score 2):

> How do I avoid X?

**Alternate Patterns:** How do I stop X?  How do I keep my Y from X?

**Suitable:** On-Topic

**Description:** These questions ask how to avoid a situation, effect, or condition.  While most questions ask in a *positive* context (How do I?), these ask from the much more difficult *negative* context (How do I not?)

**Traps to Avoid:** These questions are notoriously suceptible to being Primarily Opinion-Based (POB), meaning that the OP cannot judge which answer is better than any other without explaining the criterion for judgement.  Consequently, OPs should go out of their way to explain what makes a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to write a plot where X happens

**Alternate Patterns:** Why would X?  How do I achieve X?

**Suitable:** Off-Topic

**Description:** These questions are about a story set in a world, not about world building. They are sometimes fit for https://writing.stackexchange.com.

**Traps to Avoid:** One of the criteria an OP should use to evaluate the suitability of a question is whether or not the *circumstances* of the story materially affect the question, or whether the question is materially affected by the *circumstances* of the story.  If you can ask yourself a question similar to, "does my question depend on whether or not my protagonist has a quart of paint thinner in his backpack?" and the answer is "yes," then the question is off-topic for this site.

**Relevant Meta Links:**

- [Why is my question "Too Story Based" and how do I get it opened?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300/21222)
- [When should I close a question as "Too Story Based"?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3298/21222)

Answer (score 2):

> How to X given Y?

**Alternate Patterns:** How do I X?  How would X achieve Y (given Z)?

**Suitable:** On-Topic

**Description:** This is a very popular question type.  The OP is generally trying to understand how to achieve a goal or set of conditions given a set of circumstances, limitations, or restrictions.  For example, "how would my medieval army overcome 500 Kobolds advancing through a narrow valley?"

**Traps to Avoid:** This type of question is highly susceptible to being [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437).  There are often a great many ways a goal or condition can be achieved.  It is the OP's responsibility to provide both (a) an appropriate list of details that properly frame the question including limitations and restrictions, and (b) an explanation of how the OP will judge the best answer (or, a description of what would constitute the best answer).

**Relevant Meta Links:**

- [Why was "How can The Temple of Elementary Evil reliably protect itself against kinetic bombardment?" put on hold?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7191/my-question-was-put-on-hold-at-13-upvotes-with-no-vtc-comments/7192#7192)

Answer (score 2):

> What technology could replace X?

**Alternate pattern:** How could technology X be replaced in this context?

**Suitable:** On-topic

**Description:** OP is usually trying to create a world without the relevant technology, but with some substitute technology in place.

**Traps to avoid:** In order to make the question acceptable, it must define very well the context and the constraints for alternative technologies, otherwise it may be closed for the following reasons:

- **Primarily opinion-based** when it is not possible to objectively compare alternatives;
- **Needing more details or clarity** when the context where a substitute technology is required is not well set;
- **Requiring more focus** when the constraints of how alternative technologies might be applied is not well defined.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would someone X?

**Alternate Patterns:** What reasons would X?  Why would X?

**Suitable:** Off-Topic

**Description:** This question is asking for possible reasons or justification for a particular action or decision.  For example, "Why would somebody stay inside a burning house?"  Questions like this are almost always closed as either *too broad* or *primarily opinion-based* because without considerable scoping/context/limitation any answer is correct.  This question could be thought of as a very specific form of the "I need an *infinite list* of things" question.

Note also that questions of this type are very suceptible to being *too story-based* in that they are dependent on the circumstances of the story.  Worldbuilding (on-topic) is about systems and rules.  Storybuilding (off-topic) is about circumstances and actions.  If the question ceases to exist or no longer makes sense after removing all references to the story, it's too story-based.

*Many questions on Worldbuilding.SE have some degree of fishing-for-ideas.  However, questions that are nothing more than fishing-for-ideas (i.e., helping you write your story, not helping you build a consistent fictional world) are generally off-topic.*

**Relevant Meta Links:**

- [How can questions be closed as being "primarily opinion-based" on Worldbuilding?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5455/how-can-questions-be-closed-as-being-primarily-opinion-based-on-worldbuilding)
- [Clarification for new users: when is a "fishing for ideas" question on- or off-topic?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5621/clarification-for-new-users-when-is-a-fishing-for-ideas-question-on-or-off-t)
- [How to deal with "Please develop my High Concept" questions?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions)
- [Seeking community consensus about "Why would X lead to Y?" questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6781/seeking-community-consensus-about-why-would-x-lead-to-y-questions)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I justify/explain X?

**Suitable:** On-Topic

**Description:** This is a specific sub-type of [Why would someone X?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6338/40609).  However, it's considered on-topic because it is asking how to use or consistently apply a rule of the world, or use a particular technology in light of world rules.

However, these questions are too easily expressed as idea-generating questions, which is generally off-topic.  (See [I need an infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) vs. [I need a finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609).  See also [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) and [open-ended questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6654)).  To keep the question on-topic, the OP is expected to provide limitations, restrictions, conditions, or expected/desired outcomes to narrow the list of potential responses.

**Relevant Meta Links**

- [What makes for a good "why would" question that stays on-topic?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7390/40609)

**Advice:** A clever way to begin the process of idea-generation (introduced by our renowned Cort Ammon), is to reformat your question as "what [genre] books or movies have dealt with [open-ended-idea]?" and ask it on our sister site, [Science-Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/).  People will happily give you a ton of useful information that could (a) directly answer your question or (b) help you narrow your question so it becomes an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609) question on this site.

A general piece of advice (good for almost everything on this site), is that you should NOT ask a question, intentionally leaving details vague, because you want the widest possible response set.  That's not how Stack Exchange is designed.  Instead, decide beforehand what you're trying to achieve and express that as a condition of the question.  "Why would you use a hammer to kill someone?" would be on-topic save that it's asking for an infinite list of things — it's open-ended and primarily opinion-based.  On the other hand, "I need my victim to remain identifiable, how could a hammer be used to kill my victim?" solves the problem by expressing an expected result.

Answer (score 0):

> Could X exist?

**Alternate Patterns:** How would X evolve? What evolutionary pressures could justify X? What gene-splicing would allow X to exist?

**Suitable:** Off-Topic (note **However,** below)

**Description:** Questions like this are always *opinion-based* in that the (usually quite fantastic) creature has no terrestrial counterpart that could be used to justify the possibility or plausibility of the creature's existence. The questions are almost always asked in terms of Real Life or the theoretical application of current or near-future technologies to permit the creature to exist.

Questions like this are also *not about worldbuilding* in that they are not discussing the rules of a fictional world of the OP's creation, but the theoretical existence of a fictional creature of the OP's creation in the real world. As such, it isn't the creature that was asked about (on-topic), but the conditions of the real world that would permit the existence of the creature (off-topic, thus, not about worldbuilding).

**However:**

- Whether intentional or not, questions of this type are an effort to circumvent the rules of the [Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2797/40609). The Anatomically Correct Series is the only expression of this question that is on-topic.
- Questions of this type are specifically on-topic when asked as a [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) question against the rules of the OP's world, ***not the real world.***

**Traps to Avoid:** In the process of worldbuilding, there is a substantial difference between *justifying* a creature's existence and *proving* a creature's existence.  The difference is that the former merely addresses the needs of suspension-of-disbelief where the latter is seeking to factually demonstrate that the Frankenstein monster could be created. The former is all the OP should be looking for. The latter is the intrinsic problem with this question type and should be avoided.

Before asking a question of this type, the OP should ask themselves why they're asking it. If all they're looking for is help with [creature-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creature-design), then the question could be easily reworded to reflect, for example, "my creature has two heads, what neck and should bone structure would allow this?" This is an example of a specific creature-design question. "Specific" is always the best friend of the OP on the Worldbuilding Stack.