# Is asking for advice or critique on your world on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

[This recent question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/160558/how-to-make-my-matriarchal-society-more-realistic) is a little baffling and very long-winded, but it seems OP's intended "question" is asking for advice, critique, or feedback on their construction of their matriarchy so far.  Is this on-topic on Worldbuilding.SE?  I usually live on Writing, where asking for critique or advice is off-topic.  Is that the case here too?

Comment: I don't think it is. There is nothing *specific* to solve about that question it's more about discussion than. And it's really too broad if it's "this is my fictional world" (well, OK not the *entirety* of it but a pretty big slice).

Answer (score 5):

## OFF-TOPIC

That's the short answer.

Advice & critique are, of course, valid worldbuilding matter for discussion.  Simply off-topic for **this** forum.  Stack Exchange operates on the principle of *one focused query gets focused responses*.  Generally speaking we try to play by SE's rules as best we can, while understanding that geopoesy as an artform in its own right or as an adjunct to story writing and gamesmithing simply doesn't fit the SE mold all that well.

---

The long and short of it is you should be seeking this kind of advice & feedback on what's known as a "long form discussion forum" for in depth and potentially long term discussions, for quick advice questions, you could also try a "short form discussion forum".

For the latter, **Reddit** is best. High volume + large membership means you're very likely to get some kind of random advice. There are a lot of fantasy & sci-fi worldbuilding forums there as well as gaming forums that cater to a worldbuilding perspective. You could try [Fantasy Worldbuilding](https://www.reddit.com/r/FantasyWorldbuilding/), or for a broader scope, [Worldbuilding](https://www.reddit.com/r/FantasyWorldbuilding/).

For higher quality more in depth discussion within a real community setting, where you might get less feedback, but feedback of higher quality, I'd suggest the [**CBB**](https://cbbforum.com) or the [**ZBB**](http://www.verduria.org/index.php).

And of course, when you've got some tidbit of lore a bit polished up, feel free to submit it to the [**Universe Factory**](https://medium.com/universe-factory)!

Stack Excahnge is specifically designed to help you with relatively narrowly focused worldbuilding queries. [See What is Worldbuilding All About?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about) We'd love for you to hang around, get to know this forum better and by all means, whenever you're facing a sticky worldbuilding problem, by all means ask here! Check out our [Catalogue of Question Types](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types/6140#6140) to help you understand what we mean.

Answer (score 3):

If such a worldbuilding question was posed as a reality-check on a particular discrete portion of the setting in such a way that it did not rely solely upon personal opinion, and was not applicable only to the particular story or world in the question, and it could be asked without requiring potential answerers to read reams of material, then I'd say "Yes"... it would appear to be on- topic.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Elemtilas. Can be made on-topic if the question were presented as “here is a bullet point list of facts about my matriarchy. Are there any contradictions within this list?” That’s a specific, answerable question. Could also be on topic asking for list of historical matriarchies that could be used as a model given story constraint X. Note that just asking for a list of historical matriarchies is a question for the History stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I think we'll end up having to discuss the meaning of on topic. IMO the question is on topic but unfortunately it is too broad. It just needs to be more focused to be a valid question. An off-topic question however would not be salvageable even if it were focused from the start.