# Can I post tidbits of lore from the world I'm building here for feedback, or is this more about asking about the worldbuilding itself?

Tags: discussion

I'm working on a world that I'd like to make into a video game someday. I'd like a place to post information about it so I can get feedback, suggestions, etc. Is this the place for that? If not, where might a good place be?

Comment: No, this is a place specifically for solving worldbuilding problems you have. Do take a good look around though, you may find that the sort of things we deal with can be of help to you. Please take the tour and when you have a bit of spare time read-up in the help center about how we work. A good place? Nowhere on the network deals with questions of the "what do you think about this" opinion based type, but we can help you make things work consistently and in a structured way in your world. You could try [gaming.se] for game-designers or our list of sites: https://stackexchange.com/sites#name

Comment: maybe the structure of your question could fit. eg "does it make economical sense to have a massive continent sized elf city just 2 years after a world war where 90% of the population was lost?"

Comment: I've suddenly remembered [The Universe Factory](https://medium.com/universe-factory), you'll need to create a logon. You can post stories, vignettes, perhaps with the lore you mention and you should get some feedback, but see the sort of thing that they do before posting so you know what its about. Best of luck, see you around.

Answer (score 8):

**NO ... but ...**

I've merged this into the answer I gave to a [similar Meta query](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7607/is-asking-for-advice-or-critique-on-your-world-on-topic-here/7608#7608) a while back.

The long and short of it is you should be seeking this kind of advice & feedback on what's known as a "long form discussion forum"; or, for quick advice questions, you could also try a "short form discussion forum".

For the latter, Reddit is best. There are a lot of fantasy & sci-fi worldbuilding forums as well as gaming forums that cater to a worldbuilding perspective. You could try [Fantasy Worldbuilding](https://www.reddit.com/r/FantasyWorldbuilding/), or for a broader scope, [Worldbuilding](https://www.reddit.com/r/FantasyWorldbuilding/).

For the former, where you might get less feedback, but feedback of higher quality, I'd suggest the [**CBB**](https://cbbforum.com) or the [**ZBB**](http://www.verduria.org/index.php).

And of course, when you've got some tidbit of lore a bit polished up, feel free to submit it to the [**Universe Factory**](https://medium.com/universe-factory)!

Stack Excahnge is specifically designed to help you with relatively narrowly focused worldbuilding queries. [See What is Worldbuilding All About?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about) We'd love for you to hang around, get to know this forum better and by all means, whenever you're facing a sticky worldbuilding problem, by all means ask here! Check out our [Catalogue of Question Types](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types/6140#6140) to help you understand what we mean.

Comment: Frankly, this is the answer I wish I could have written. Thanks for the resources, interesting looking places.

Comment: @Tantalus'touch. -- You'd certainly be welcome at CBB! Other places too, I'm sure. Anyway -- it was you that reminded me about Universe Factory!